# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class, new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to edit the default scaffolding, and have been thus far quite successful. However, this little puzzle has managed to boggle me, as even reverting the file to it's original state isn't working. It's throwing up a "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" as the title suggests.

New Action In User Controller:

```
def new
  if @current_user
    redirect_to(action: 'home')
  else
    @user = User.new
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb beginning

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from    being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In which line? which file?

Comment: @Mindbreaker First line of the _form.html.erb.

Comment: do you have an user model? or maybe you deleted it?

Comment: I would try starting a rails console and doing 'user = User.new' to make sure the model is working like you think it should.

Comment: @Mattherick User model is present.

Comment: @andrunix It's working as far as I can tell, User.new gives a good user object...

Answer (score 0):

In the case when `@current_user` is set, your `new` action doesn't stop executing after the `redirect_to`.  Execution proceeds to the `respond_to` block, which attempts to render the page *without* setting `@user`, resulting in the error you're getting.

Possible solutions:

1. Use a before filter—Execution of the current action is halted if a before filter triggers a redirect.  This is standard Rails practice.

   ```
   before_filter :check_for_current_user, only: [:new]

   def new
     @user = User.new

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # new.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @user }
     end
   end

   protected

   def check_for_current_user
     redirect_to(action: 'home') if @current_user
   end
   ```
2. Just return early.

   ```
   def new
     if @current_user
       redirect_to(action: 'home') and return
     end

     @user = User.new

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # new.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @user }
     end
   end
   ```

Cite: [http://excid3.com/blog/execution-after-redirect-vulnerability](http://excid3.com/blog/execution-after-redirect-vulnerability/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be working. I might need to do some further study into the model, because none of the actions are currently working...